# Angular modules and dependency injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

Let's say: I use a module called `constants`.

```
angular.module("constants", [])
.constant("A", 10);
```

I want to use this constant `A` in another module:

```
angular.module("moduleThatUseConstants", ["constants"])
.service("B", ["A", Services.B]); // here I use A
```

That works ! But what if I already have another constant (or controller etc) called `A` ?

```
angular.module("moduleThatUseConstants", ["constants"])
.service("A", [Services.A]); 
.service("B", ["A", Services.B]); // ???
```

**Question:** How to specify that `A` comes from the module `constants` ? I tried:

```
.service("B", ["constants.A", Services.B]);
```

But that doesn't work `$injector:unpr Unknown Provider "constants.A"`

Comment: if you already have _another constant (or controller etc) called A_ will be used last included, you can't specify from where take services

Comment: It's logical that it will use "last included A". But can't I specify the source (module) of the dependency ?

Comment: you can't specify, possibly it resolved in angular 2.0

Comment: as workaround you can use prefixes like in your sample `angular.module("constants", [])
.constant("constants.A", 10);` and use it like `.service("B", ["constants.A", Services.B]); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot achieve this. The later one with the same name will always be resolved. This is one of the shortcomings of DI in Angular 1.x. I expect to see a solution to this in the Angular 2 DI.